# The `transform:` element doesn't seem to work on hover?

Tags: css, reactjs, hover, transform, vite

I'm trying to make a zoom in animation on an image, the hover property works, but transform seems not to be working. Didn't find a solution that worked online.

React App:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${Stars})`,
      backgroundsize: '100%'
  }}>
      
      <img src= {Prince} className='Prince'/>
      <img src= {Headphones} className='Headphones' />  
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

CSS for the image:

```
.Headphones {
  /* Positioning */
  grid-column: 4 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  max-width: 20vw;
  max-height: 20vh;
  place-self: center;
  z-index: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Float animation */
  animation: shake 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  transition: transform 0.25s;
}
.Headphones:hover {
  transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

I'm expecting for the image to zoom in on hover.